# ngbDropdownMenu.close() on multiple dropdowns

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, ng-bootstrap

I'm working on a data visualizer project. In this project users need to be able to make look ups to make it easy to find cretin data quickly. To do this I'm am using `ngbDropdownMenu` from [NgBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples). They click a button and a little dropdown menu pops up so they can make a new look up.

When the menu pops up. They give a name and description to the new look up and hit submit. It will then create a new look up and fire an event I made so that I can close the dropdown menu `NgbDropdownMenu.close();`

#### HTML for the dropdown menu

```
<div ngbDropdown  id="caseCodeDropdown" 
                  (openChange)="openChange($event);" 
                  class="input-group-append d-inline-block col-sm-1 px-0 mx-0">
    <button ngbDropdownToggle class="btn btn-sm btn-outline" type="button" >
         <i class="fal fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu>
        <newLookUpComponent></newLookUpComponent>
     </div>
</div>
```

#### Component for dropdown menu

```
@ViewChild(NgbDropdownMenu) caseCodeDropdown: NgbDropdownMenu;

public dropdownCloseSub: Subscription = new Subscription;

constructor(private _eventEmitterService: EventEmitterService) { }

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dropdownCloseSub = this._eventEmitterService.invokeSubmitNewMatterCode.subscribe(() => {
            this.caseCodeDropdown.dropdown.close();
        });
}
```

This works perfectly. The problem is when I need to have more than one dropdown menus on one page. I have five look ups for one of the pages and when I use the code below it only works for the `caseCodeDropdown` which is the first dropdown from the top of the html doc.

#### HTML with more than one dropdown menu

```
<div ngbDropdown  id="caseCodeDropdown" 
                  (openChange)="openChange($event);" 
                  class="input-group-append d-inline-block col-sm-1 px-0 mx-0">
    <button ngbDropdownToggle class="btn btn-sm btn-outline" type="button" >
         <i class="fal fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu>
        <newLookUpComponent></newLookUpComponent>
     </div>
</div>

<div ngbDropdown  id="fileNoDropdown" 
                  (openChange)="openChange($event);" 
                  class="input-group-append d-inline-block col-sm-1 px-0 mx-0">
    <button ngbDropdownToggle class="btn btn-sm btn-outline" type="button" >
         <i class="fal fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu>
        <newLookUpComponent></newLookUpComponent>
     </div>
</div>

<div ngbDropdown  id="OPCDropdown" 
                  (openChange)="openChange($event);" 
                  class="input-group-append d-inline-block col-sm-1 px-0 mx-0">
    <button ngbDropdownToggle class="btn btn-sm btn-outline" type="button" >
         <i class="fal fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu>
        <newLookUpComponent></newLookUpComponent>
     </div>
</div>
```

#### Component  with more than one dropdown menu

```
@ViewChild(NgbDropdownMenu) caseCodeDropdown: NgbDropdownMenu;
@ViewChild(NgbDropdownMenu) fileNoDropdown: NgbDropdownMenu;
@ViewChild(NgbDropdownMenu) OPCDropdown: NgbDropdownMenu;

public dropdownCloseSub: Subscription = new Subscription;

constructor(private _eventEmitterService: EventEmitterService) { }

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dropdownCloseSub = this._eventEmitterService.invokeSubmitNewMatterCode.subscribe(() => {
            this.caseCodeDropdown.dropdown.close();
            this.fileNoDropdown.dropdown.close();
            this.OPCDropdown.dropdown.close();
        });
}
```

## WHAT I HAVE TRIED

First I tried

```
@ViewChild("caseCodeDropdown") caseCodeDropdown: NgbDropdownMenu;
@ViewChild("fileNoDropdown") fileNoDropdown: NgbDropdownMenu;
@ViewChild("OPCDropdown") OPCDropdown: NgbDropdownMenu;
```

Using `@ViewChild()` passing in the id of the element left all the `caseCodeDropDown, fileNoDropdown, OPCDropdown` as undefinded. I was unable to close them.

Next

```
var target = document.getElementId('caseCodeDropdown');
```

The problem with this method is I'm unable to use the `ngbDropdownMenu` functions. `target.dropdown.close()` throws an error.

Is there any other way I can get the element by its ID and still use the `ngbDropdownMenu` functions.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Run close in a for loop

Comment: @dota2pro this does not work. It still will only close the first dropdown menu in the HTML DOC

Comment: if you can add a stackblitz example then it will be easy to debug

Comment: Did you find any solution? @JacobLoncar